# returned array being assigned as null to variable in PHP

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a function in `PHP` which calls another class function in order to assign a value to one of it's variables `$related`.

The original function requiring the value uses the `requestACLForAccess()` function to add a specific variable `filter` to the `$headers` variable:

The `listRecords` function:

```
    public function listRecords($api)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    if ($this->authenticationProcedure() !== false) {
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        $access = $this->requestACLForAccess($headers['module'], $headers['oauth_token'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        if(gettype($access) == "array"){
        $headers['filter'][0][$access[1]]['$equals'] = $access[2];
        }
        $listObject = new FilterApi();;
        return $listObject->filterList($api, $headers);
    }
}
```

The function `requestACLForAccess` being called :

```
protected function requestACLForAccess(
    $targetModule,
    $token,
    $req_type,
    $getSpecialFlag = false,
    $targetId = null
) {
    $row = $this->checkTokenValid("token", $token);
    if (!empty($row) || $row !== false) {
        $related = \Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\custom\clients\base\CustomACL::checkRelated($row['module'], $targetModule, $row['id'], $req_type, $getSpecialFlag, $targetId);
        die(gettype($related)); // For debugging
        return $related;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function that was called is in another file called `customACL.php`. Within that function, a certain conditional statement returns an `array $arr` which should be assigned to the particular variable above. The function being called:

```
    public static function checkRelated($module, $targetModule, $id, $req_type, $getSpecial, $targetId)
{
  $bean = \BeanFactory::retrieveBean($module, $id);
  if($bean->designation == self::ADMIN_NAME && !(in_array($targetModule, self::RECORD_RELATION_MODULES))){
    return self::ACL_ADMIN;
  } else{
    //first check if a relational table between modules exists
    $query = "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%{$module}%{$targetModule}%' OR table_name like '%{$targetModule}%{$module}%'";
    $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (empty($row)) { //if no table exists
       return self::ACL_ADMIN;
    } else { //find out table name
        $table_name = $row['table_name'];
        if ($req_type == 'PUT' || $req_type == 'DELETE' || $req_type == 'GET') { //check if record has relation
        $acl_access = self::checkRecordRelated($table_name, $id, $module, $req_type, $targetId, $targetModule);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For my specific call, this function then goes to a `checkRecordRelated()` function within the same file:

```
  protected static function checkRecordRelated($table_name, $id, $module, $req_type, $targetId, $targetModule)
{
    //find out module column name in relational table
    $query = "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$table_name' and column_name like '%{$module}_id%' or column_name like '%{$module}s_id%'";
    $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (empty($row)) {//if no column name
        return self::ACL_NON_ADMIN;
    } else {//return module column name
        $column_name = $row['column_name'];
    }

    if ($req_type == 'GET') {//if special GET request
        //find if related records exist in relational table for listing
        $findRelatedRecords = "select * from $table_name where $column_name = '$id' and 'deleted' = 0";
        $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($findRelatedRecords);
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        if (empty($row)) {//if NON_ADMIN exist
            return self::ACL_NON_ADMIN;
        } else {//if exist
            $arr = array(self::ACL_ADMIN, $table_name, $id);
            return $arr;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Up until the point where I have defined the variable `$arr`, checking with `gettype()` returns an array and printing the variable gives me (as expected) a complete array with the values I've added. However, as soon as the value is returned to the original function and assigned to the variable `$related`, the array somehow becomes `NULL` and the gettype() also returns `NULL`.

**Update**: I've added the missing functions to make it clearer, I hope it makes sense

Could anyone tell me what naive mistake am I doing here? Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see the relationship bewteen your two snippets. Where is `requestACLForAccess` being called? Also "please note this point" is not accurate enough. What exactly is happening on those lines that shouldn't?

Comment: @Jeto updated the question. Hope it's better understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing, I forgot to return the `$aclaccess` variable in the `checkrelated()` function which is why it was showing null. Adding the return value was the solution.